# 18.04.1 Black Screen after suspend

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, nvidia, suspend

On my Lenovo Y900 on both Ubuntu 16.04.2 and 18.04.1, since upgrading from kernel 4.10 to 4.13 (and later 4.15 and currently 4.18.5-041805-generic), after waking up from suspend screen becomes dead. I can login through SSH, I can blindly switch to command line and reboot, sound works etc. It's not a matter of backlight / brightness - tried to edit parameters over SSH with no result. Also setting nouveaus modeset to 0 didn't help.

Ubuntu 18.04.1
4.18.5-041805-generic
NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 980M] with latest Nouveau drivers from ubuntu repo.

EDIT 08.2021 - same happens under nvidia's 470 driver on both 18.04 and 20.04 Ubuntus. Rolling back to 460 has helped. What is more strange, sometimes log is empty! Supspending machine is logged, then sometimes (but not always) is dumped trace if NViadia has thrown warning during attempt to unsuspend... And then is only booting procedure after power cycle, after unsuccessful unsuspending.

Comment: Try see if the problem exist when using standard bionic kernal 4.15.0-33 with proprietary nvidia drivers 390.

Comment: When using 4.15.0-33 with NVidia 390 drivers suspending works.
When using 4.18.5- and/or Nouveau drivers problem exists.

Comment: I'm guessing it's more or a nouveau bug than the kernel, at least you have something that works until you can find a solution for the setup that you prefer.